# Finding inverse function of a function with multiple variable

Tags: inverse-function

First, I'll say that english isn't my first language and that I'm not studying math in english, so I'll probably say some stuff wrong.

Anyway, what I was wondering is how to find the inverse function of a function that has multiple variables? Because in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (in two dimensions), it's pretty simple, you can just exchange x and y and then isolate y. But is it possible in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ or even in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

To make it clearer, take the simplest function possible, like:
$z=x+y$ (another one could do the job too, I just didn't have a particular function in mind)
What will be the inverse function? In my head the whole concept of inverse function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, when $n\gt2$, isn't clear..

If you can help me or if I'm not clear enough, let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: You can only find the inverse of a function if it is bijective (1-1)  $z=x+y$ is not bijective.  i.e. $f(0,1) = f(1,0)$  While there are bijective function from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ they aren't as common, they are not smooth functions, and finding the inverse is not such an important activity.

Comment: Even if you have a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,$ finding the inverse isn't so easy.  In many cases, we have to be satisfied with proving it exists.  This is true even in $\mathbb{R}^1.$  We can say that $10^x$ has an inverse, but when it comes to giving a formula, all we can say is, "Let's call the inverse the logarithm."  In fact, the same goes for square an square root.